# Creating an weekly inventory level table from two datasets

Tags: pandas, inventory-management

I have two dataset, one with inventory data, like this

```
    Item Number Date    Inventory
0   064-01-1347 06/17/2023  3561
1   064-01-1361 06/17/2023  4035
2   064-01-1375 06/17/2023  2684
3   064-01-1385 06/17/2023  5136
4   064-01-1399 06/17/2023  6399
```

and another with inventory data like this,

```
    Item Number Inventory Receive   Total Item Qty
0   064-13-0002 07/07/2023  700
1   064-13-0338 07/07/2023  1700
2   064-13-0340 07/07/2023  1000
3   064-13-0353 07/07/2023  1900
4   064-13-0416 07/07/2023  1000
```

I have to make a table based on Item Number and weekly dates inventory level for each item, how to do that?

The two datasets have details of several items that gets delivered on various days over a period of 3 months, but each item has a different delivery date, so grouping and summation over unique items don't really give a straight result  to be converted into a pivot table, as i get a lot of null values,

The output table should be of this format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qggAm.jpg)

If not, what should be done?

my expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVdCs.jpg)

Comment: Your question is unclear, please break down the exact logic and provide the matching expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not only showing samples of your input dataframe(s) but also expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you make sure the expected output is in a text format (like your inputs) and matches the data in your example (not just dummy numbers)

Comment: @mozway The expected output is the format i was given, I don't have an output

Comment: @Ankur given the two minimal dataframes that you provided, can you craft the expected output manually?

Comment: I tried but got a lot of null values and had to fill in with mean values or 0 and i don't know how to display inventory levels or what does inventory levels mean?

Comment: I meant, can you do it manually, to show us what you really expect?

Comment: @mozway I expected an output like the one i will add in the question below now, but the values are not as expected, in the dummy one, the values were increasing, but i got mixed values